# If an operation can be represented with other associative operations can we assume it is associative?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

From what I can find it seems that to show an operation operation $\oplus$ is associative, you must show that $(A\oplus B) \oplus C \equiv A \oplus (B \oplus C)$. If $\oplus$ can be represented with purely associative operations does it follow that $\oplus$ is also associative?

For example, take $\oplus$ to be a symmetric difference set operator. Since
$$
A \oplus B = A \cup B - A\cap B = (A\cup B) \cap \overline{(A\cap B)}
$$

can we say that $\oplus$ is associative as it can be represented by known associative operations?

Comment: With your example, it doesn't seem obvious at all from the algebraic definition that it's going to be associative, but it does seem obvious that it's going to be commutative. Also, note that your formula uses union and intersection **and set difference**, and set difference is not associative.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not true in general.  Ordinary addition and multiplication are associative on $\mathbb{R}$.  However, the operation $\odot$ on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
a \odot b = a^2+ab = a(a+b)
$$
is not associative, as you can check.  One quick way to see this is to note that $1 \odot (1 \odot 2) \neq (1 \odot 1) \odot 2$.

Comment: Thanks you for your help

Comment: @Qualia Note that we can even get away with a single binary operation: $$a\star b:=a+(a+b)$$ is not associative in $\mathbb{Z}$, since e.g. $(2\star 3)\star 1=15$ but $2\star (3\star 1)=11$.